# save captured image to MySQL database using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, mysql, opencv

I have a piece of code that captures an image from my internal webcam on my laptop. With this image, I would like to send it directly to my MySQL database. here is the code.

```
import cv2
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from time import sleep
import serial

# Obtain connection string information from the portal
config = {
  'host':'oursystem.mysql.database.azure.com',
  'user':'user',
  'password':'pass',
  'database':'projectdb'
}

try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Camera (img BLOB);")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

frame = cap.read()[1]
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Camera (img) VALUES %s",frame)
cap.release()
```

As you guys see, I am trying to directly send an image that was captured and saved in the "frame" variable in my database, but it does not work.

please someone help me

error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'ndarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image into base64 string and store that as text feild into your mysql database. At display time you can base64_decode the image and display.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: how i can do that with python?

Comment: go through the following link this might help you https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html

Comment: @chr Hamza You need to change the type of column blob to text.

Comment: @NIRAMAL TANDEL i change the type to LONGBLOB and it's working

Comment: Ok. I didn't tried with LONGBLOB type.  Thanks for letting me know.